# Architecture for a AWS Lambda Scraper

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, queue, amazon-rds

I am probably spinning this already too much in my mind and would like to have some input on how to best architect a web scraper in a serverless environment

What I am working on is a simple forum scraper that provides users statistics on how their posts are being liked, word count per sub-forum etc.

My idea was that my:

1. Static website sends a user id to a lambda manager function
2. Manager checks if this user has been scraped before in an RDS and calculates a delta in case
3. Manager sends back a job id, creates adds the URLs for scraping in a queue
4. Scrapers get triggered by items in the queue that process the posts
5. Static website pulls the manager for status on the job
6. <<< how does the manager now know if the job is complete (I cannot filter SQS, that would be against its purpose and the scraper jobs work independently and concurrent so they would also not know if a certain URL was the last URL for this job.
7. On request, Manager recognizes job complete, saves the generated data as a CSV file on s3
8. The static website pulls the generated CSV file and processes further

What would be the right architecture to avoid the conundrum in point 6? The way I thought would be to use the RDS instead to save URLs with a jobID and a parse status and if all URLs of this job have the correct status I would know how to respond but I have the feeling I am overengineering this?

Comment: Job status can be kept somewhere. For example your scrapers update their job processing status in a DynamoDB table. Manager lambda checks the table for completed jobs. Alternative is to have other SQS queue. Scrapers publish complete-job-messages into it and manager lambda pulls the second queue for completed jobs.

Comment: Thanks, but this would again mean that the scraper need to do a dB update (Avg 0.17sec, so if possible I wanted to avoid that ). Regarding 2nd job queue, can you explain that one a bit more? That would mean I need to pull all complete msg with the manager aws lambda and evaluate? That doesn't seem right to me either.

Comment: Now I think about using a DB trigger per transaction, that checks if the condition is fulfilled rather than having a separate function checking this periodically - I think this could solve it.

Comment: Worth trying in my view.